# Relationship between E(X), E(Y), E(XY), V(X), Var(Y)

Tags: self-study, variance, random-variable, expected-value

Which of the following is **NOT** possible?

> 1. $E(X) = 0.5, E(Y) = 0.5, E(XY) = 0.6$
> 2. $E(X^2) = 0.5, E(Y^2) = 0.5, E(X)E(Y) = 0.6$
> 3. $V(X) = 0.5, V(Y) = 0.5, E(XY) = 0.6$
> 4. $\Pr (X>0) = 0.5, \Pr (Y>0) = 0.5, \Pr (X>Y) = 0.5$
> 5. None of the given options

I know option 4 is possible, if $X$ and $Y$ are normally distributed with mean = 0.

However, I am not sure how to proceed with the other 3 options.

edit:
I have tried using the covariance formula `Cov(X,Y) = E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)` for option 1, but it doesn't really prove anything.

I'm practicing this for an upcoming stats paper, and I got this question from a past year's stats paper.

Comment: Welcome to CV. If this question relates to a class exercise, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the tag to modify the question accordingly.

Comment: Hint: $E[(X-Y)^2]=E[X^2]+E[Y^2]-2E[XY].$

Comment: @whuber which option is this hint applicable to? 

i tried using it on option 2, and it seems the covariance has to be negative for the values to hold, which seems entirely possible. No clue how to apply it to option 1/3

Comment: Second hint: the square of any real quantity is never negative.

Comment: @whuber right, so E[(X-Y)^2] should be non-negative.

$E[(X-Y)^2] = 0.5 + 0.5 - 2E(XY)$

but in general, $E(XY) != E(X)E(Y)$.

I can't see where else i can apply this hint

Comment: What I would suggest it to go through the four options and, for each, either find an example where it holds or find a demonstration of impossibility.  In this way you will be able to narrow your post down to a single question (or perhaps a pair of closely related questions, understanding how expectations of squares and products are so closely related to variances and covariances).